# Run startx over SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, xorg, tty

This question has been asked several times, but the solutions I've found always solve the problem in a different way.

On the remote machine (the one on which I want to run `startx`), I have already

```
echo allowed_users=anybody | sudo tee /etc/X11/Xwrapper.config
```

When I ssh to the machine and run `startx;`, I get the error,

```
Fatal server error:
(EE) parse_vt_settings: Cannot open /dev/tty0 (Permission denied)
```

I added myself to the `tty` group after which the error is

```
Fatal server error:
(EE) xf86OpenConsole: Cannot open virtual console 2 (Permission denied)
```

Speculating, when I log in to the machine locally, `getty` (running as `root`) assigns ownership of `tty0` to my user, and this is *sine qua non*. How can I make this assignment happen without typing my username and password on that virtual terminal? Maybe I can send keystrokes to the virtual terminal? Maybe I can `chown` the right files so that I can own it?

Of course this is a ["XY" problem](http://xyproblem.info/). The **real** problem is: when I'm away, I would like to log into the machine (*e.g.* after a reboot) and turn on its monitor (a projector in this case) so that my family can watch movies on my profile without knowing or having to type my password.

Comment: I dont think using ssh would help, even after the permissions problem is solved.  Something like VNC (server launched on startup) might be a better fit. The problem is even if you do get your ssh solution working I posit it will send the screen over the SSH connection, not to both the ssh connection and console. (Also, you probably dont have X forwarding set on the client side)

Comment: @davidgo Thanks for the comment. I don't want X forwarding over SSH. I want X to take control of TTY0 just like it would if I typed my credentials in there and ran `startx;`.

Comment: Can you lunch startx by changing the runlevel (ie runlevel 5)?  Relatedly, why does your system not start X on startup and how is it configured to not do so?

Comment: I use arch linux. The default is not to start X unless specifically configured to do so. I don't run a desktop manager either. Run level...interesting. I don't know how that will help me give control of tty0 to X, but I'd be interested in hearing a more concrete suggestion!

Comment: I've never used arch, but have a look at https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SysVinit#Runlevel_invocation

Answer (score 2):

I hit this exact same problem and was able to get past it with `sudo chmod g+r /dev/tty3`. But I don't fully understand it, so YMMV.

Comment: Wow, great idea! How did you decide to do this? You just looked at the permissions and noted that "r" permission was missing and gave it a shot? I'll have to try that next time!

Comment: Yes, precisely. When I got the first "permission denied" error, I ran `ls -l` on the file, which revealed that it was owned by the group `tty`, which I added myself to, just as you did. When the error message changed, I looked harder at the group permissions, and noticed it had the `g+w` bit but not the `g+r` bit set. I don't know why, or what the broader implications are of setting it with `chmod`, or whether it will stick.

Comment: I assume a restart will reset the permissions (because `/dev/tty*` are virtual files put there by the kernel), but that's not a big deal. I can add the permission change to whatever script I use to do this in the future. Thanks!