# Cannot run startx from GNU screen session

Tags: linux, arch-linux, xorg, gnu-screen

I would like to run `startx` from a `screen` session. This used to work until a few years back. It seems to have been disabled to prevent people from running their X servers via `ssh`.

**Errors:**

1. `/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg.wrap: Only console users are allowed to run the X server`. This can be fixed by allowing it explicitly, by adding `allowed_users = anybody` to `/etc/X11/Xwrapper.config`
2. `parse_vt_settings: Cannot open /dev/tty0 (Permission denied)`. I have no idea how to fix this.

**Reason for running `startx` from `screen`** is that otherwise the console under the X server remains open and would be exposed in case the X server crashes, giving access to whatever privileges the user running the console has. For most people, this is not a concern since they will start the X server at startup with a display magager or refrain from running an X server at all.

**Software is:** Arch GNU/Linux kernel 5.3.1, Xorg 1.20.5, Xorg-xinit 1.4.1, GNU screen 4.7.0

**Related question:** [Run startx over SSH](https://superuser.com/q/1431441/164391). Tries to run `startx` from `ssh` (so the situation is different), but receives the same errors. An approach suggested in the comments is to work with runlevels (which Arch does not have by default; it may be possible to achieve the same with systemd.targets instead). This seems to suggest that there is no way around the second error above that would work without breaking the system in a bad way. However, this might be different for the present problem with `screen` instead of `ssh`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Reason for running startx from screen is that otherwise the console under the X server remains open and would be exposed in case the X server crashes, giving access to whatever privileges the user running the console has.

Well, I'm not sure how exactly Screen would avoid this at all – but the core problem is already avoidable by using `exec` to launch startx, which causes the console's shell process to be *replaced by* the startx process. Once startx exits for any reason, the console is left with no master process and has no other option but to return to the login prompt.

> It seems to have been disabled to prevent people from running their X servers via ssh.

No; it was disabled to avoid needing to give root privileges (the setuid bit) to /usr/bin/Xorg.

Previously the X server would be setuid so that it could open a new virtual console, input devices, etc. Now the "rootless" mode is used which starts Xorg with only the same privileges that you already have, and it attempts to directly draw on the virtual console corresponding to the tty it's on.

(Not to be confused with the other "rootless" mode, which doesn't have the so-called "root window" corresponding to the entire desktop, and only applies to Xwin.)

However, in terminal multiplexers, and/or terminal emulators, and/or remote shell connections, there *is* no virtual console.

> parse_vt_settings: Cannot open /dev/tty0 (Permission denied). I have no idea how to fix this.

Explicitly specify the correct virtual console to use, using the `vt#` parameter:

```
startx -- vt1
```